# What is the proper way to communicate between an Activity and a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I have a BroadcastReceiver which listens to system intents such as `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED`. When it receives one, the Activity needs to refresh its the data it presents.
Of course, the Activity may not have focus, or may not even be running when this happens. What is the proper way to "leave a message" for the next time the Activity gains focus?

I thought of storing a boolean in the SharedPreferences, but something tells me this is not the right way to go.

Comment: Ignore the `BroadcastReceiver` for the moment. When your app starts up fresh, with a brand-new process, where is the `Activity` getting its data from?

Comment: The app generates its own data and populates a SQLite database, or loads its data from the database if it's already populated. The BroadcastReceiver would "notify" the app that it has to regenerate its data. For performance reasons, the objective is to avoid regenerating the data unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the proper way to "leave a message" for the next time the Activity gains focus?

IMHO, you have four separate issues here:

**Issue #1**: How does the `BroadcastReceiver` tell a running `Activity` that an event occurred that may be of interest?

Solution: Use an event bus (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto), and post a package-added event from the receiver on the bus. Your activity can be registered for events from the bus while it is in the foreground, and it can update its view on the data when your event is received.

**Issue #2**: How does the `BroadcastReceiver` update the model data in the SQLite database when the broadcast occurs?

Solution: Delegate this, plus the receiver's side of the event bus logic, to an `IntentService`, as you need a background thread to do the database I/O. Post the event on the bus when the work is completed.

**Issue #3**: So, what happens if my activity is not in the foreground at the time the event goes out, but the activity exists (i.e., is in the background)?

Solution: Either reload your data in `onResume()` or use some sort of a "sticky" event with the bus. `LocalBroadcastManager` does not offer that, but greenrobot's EventBus has the notion of sticky events, and Square's Otto has a related `@Producer` construct.

**Issue #4**: What happens if I do not have an activity instance at all? For example, the package is added when my process is not running, so Android forks a process for me and invokes my receiver, but I have no UI code at all in my process right now?

Solution: Do nothing special. Your existing "load-the-data" logic will handle this case.

Comment: Thank you for this very comprehensive break-down of the problems. And thank you for your book as well, by the way.

Comment: @executifs: You're very welcome. BTW, I have chapters in the book on the event buses, which would cover issue #1. I don't think I have any sticky/`@Producer` samples at the moment, though.

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution can be a static variable flag in Broadcastreceiver. Once receiver receives intent, make flag=true.

Activity when gains focus can look at this static variable and can refresh data accordingly and turn this static flag to false.

Comment: I had come up with this solution as well, but for some reason it feels a little dirty to me. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you are trying to do when the `Intent` is received. If you only want to refresh the content, the the proper way is to use the `onResume` and `onStop`to attach the broadcast receiver listener. This will only work while the activity is on the foreground, so every time the user enters the activity again you need to reload the list to avoid the case that this intent arrived while not in foreground.

Another way to proceed if you want to listen it while you are not showing your UI is to create a `Service` that listens to this `Intent` with the `BroadcastReceiver`. Again it depends of the moments you need to receive this event.

To sum up:

- For foreground UI: `onResume` to attach and `onPause` to detach.
- For background: use a `Service`